# cant load data in hive table,table created with partitioned by. Told me wrong with 'hive.partition doesn't

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

**when i load data into hive,it told me wrong with 'hive.partition doesn't exists'**

centos7.2
hive 0.12
hadoop 2.7.6

---------------line  ---------

when I create the table, using the external table into MySQL,

the detail is:

```
create external table people(id int,name string)

partitioned by (logdate string,hour string) row format delimited

fields terminated by ',';
```

but! it takes wrong when I load data.

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hive.PARTITIONS' doesn't exist
```

so I check databases and tables in MySQL. And database hive has existed, but table partition really not exists.

then, I found a table name like that  -->partition_keys

```
mysql> show tables;
+---------------------------+
| Tables_in_hive            |
+---------------------------+
| BUCKETING_COLS            |
| CDS                       |
| COLUMNS_V2                |
| DATABASE_PARAMS           |
| DBS                       |
| PARTITION_KEYS            |
| SDS                       |
| SD_PARAMS                 |
```

then I describe and select that table (partition_keys)

```
mysql> describe PARTITION_KEYS;
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| TBL_ID       | bigint(20)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| PKEY_COMMENT | varchar(4000) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| PKEY_NAME    | varchar(128)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| PKEY_TYPE    | varchar(767)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| INTEGER_IDX  | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> select * from PARTITION_KEYS;
+--------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| TBL_ID | PKEY_COMMENT | PKEY_NAME | PKEY_TYPE | INTEGER_IDX |
+--------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|      1 | NULL         | hour      | string    |           1 |
|      1 | NULL         | logdate   | string    |           0 |
|      6 | NULL         | hour      | string    |           1 |
|      6 | NULL         | logdate   | string    |           0 |
+--------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

my metadata is in it.

but I can't load data into the hive table I made yet. how can I do that?

I found it couldn't change the table name into partition caused by the keyword of MySQL is partition either.

I need help, it has taken me a lot of time to deal with it. thx.

**------------------update to upload my hive-site.xml-----------------------------**

this site couldn't fill more than 30000 characters. And i just use the default configuration  `cp -r hive-default.xml hive-site.xml` . So that i just make some change in this default site  as following:

- `<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name>
  <value>false</value>
  </property>`
- `<property>
  <name>hive.server2.thrift.sasl.qop</name>
  <value>auth</value>
  <description>Sasl QOP value; Set it to one of following values to enable higher levels of
   protection for hive server2 communication with clients.
    "auth" - authentication only (default)
    "auth-int" - authentication plus integrity protection
    "auth-conf" - authentication plus integrity and confidentiality protection
   This is applicable only hive server2 is configured to use kerberos authentication.
  </description>
  </property>`
- `<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;useSSL=false</value>
  <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
  </property>`
- `<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
  <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
  </property>`

other changes are the connect name,passsword. Without doing anything about the hive-site.xml.

Comment: show the query that you used to load the data

Comment: i had try for 2 versions. First is   `alter table  add if not exists partition(logdate=20170309,hour=00) location 'hdfs://localhost:9000/hive/20170309/00/people.txt' `      second is `load data inpath 'hdfs://localhost:9000/hive/20170309/00/people.txt' overwrite into table people `

Comment: but it always return code1 with mistake about none of table named hive.partition. So,it had make another mistake about cannot add foreign key .

Comment: try this query: "load data inpath 'hdfs://localhost:9000/hive/20170309/00/people.txt' overwrite into table people partition (logdate=20170309,hour=00);"

Comment: i tried, but the same result of that. And it has returned   `FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask`

Comment: perhaps the configuration problem? maybe i should upload my hive-site.xml?

Comment: try uploading it, and also put more tags to your question, that would increase the question audience

Comment: i had upload a bit changes i made. I was using the hive-default.xml for the template. The part i uploaded is in the body i have edited.

Comment: seems that hive looks for partition meta in another table. just a hack - try to create a table named "partitions" in mysql "hive" db with exactly the same schema as in "partition_keys" and exactly the same data rows, then try loading hive data again